# Tailwind setup not working on vercel-tuborepo with react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

I was **trying to setup tailwind css with my react monorepo created using vercel-turborepo**
I simply **used the example from vercel to setup monorepo with create-react-app** then i **tried copying the same files which they have provided to setup the repo with tailwind but it is not working**
**The css is not getting applied to any component**

**This is my react monorepo folder structure in which**
1] react-monorepo = project folder
2] apps = contains two react apps client and admin also included simple CRUD API's with express
3] node_modules = common node modules of entire project
4] packages folder = contains common component of two react app inside ui folder and other folder includes shared configs
5] apps and package are two workspace defined in root level package.json of react-monorepo folder

Here are the contains of key files

**1] package.json from apps/admin**

```
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*",
    "clean": "rm -rf build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "ui": "*",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.5",
    "eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "tsconfig": "*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwind-config": "*",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**2] tailwind.config from apps/admin/tailwind.config.ts**

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import sharedConfig from "tailwind-config/tailwind.config.ts";

const config: Pick<Config, "presets"> = {
  presets: [sharedConfig],
};

export default config;
```

**3] postcss.config.js from apps/admin/postcss.config.js**

```
// If you want to use other PostCSS plugins, see the following:
// https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

**4] index.css from apps/admin/src/index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**5] shared tailwind config package.json from packages/tailwind-config/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tailwind-config",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "files": ["tailwind.config.ts"],
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

**6]** ** shared tailwind config  from packages/tailwind-config/tailwind.config.ts**

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./apps/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "../../packages/ui/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

**7] shared ui components package.json from packages/ui/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup src/index.tsx --format cjs --dts --external react",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "dev": "tsup src/index.tsx --format cjs --watch --dts --external react",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "tsconfig": "*",
    "tsup": "^6.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwind-config": "*",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13"
  }
}
```

**8]** **shared ui components tailwind config from packages/ui/tailwind.config.ts**

```
// tailwind config is required for editor support
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import sharedConfig from "tailwind-config/tailwind.config.ts";

const config: Pick<Config, "prefix" | "presets"> = {
  prefix: "ui-",
  presets: [sharedConfig],
};

export default config;
```

**9] the postcss.config.js from packages/ui/postcss.config.js is same as apps/admin/postcss.config.js (3rd)
10] the index.css from packages/ui/src/index.css contains tailwind imports and the css file is also imported in index.tsx from  packages/ui/src/index.tsx
**
Let me know in comments if you need more inputs from my side .

Your help is appreciated thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

What is difference between using presets and just spreading the object from shared config ? like this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

import sharedConfig from "tailwind-config/tailwind.config.ts";

module.exports = {
  ...sharedConfig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for Tailwind [presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets).

> The presets option lets you specify a different configuration to use as your base, making it easy to package up a set of customizations that you’d like to reuse across projects.

If you like this approach, you can define the main config file in your shared `tailwind-config` package and then use it as a preset in each of the other projects.

1. Create a new file called `tailwind-preset.js`
2. Add all of your preferred configurations. Ex:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
};
```

3. Add the preset to the other `tailwind.config.js` files

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  presets: [require("../../packages/tailwind-config/tailwind-preset.js")],
};
```

---

This [GitHub comment](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3277#issuecomment-1090064937) offers a different solution for managing shared configs in a monorepo.

Also see the section on [installing Tailwind in a React app](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

Comment: I simply spread the object from shared config to the main config not sure what is the difference ?